# How to create a divided border-bottom using html/css?

Tags: html, css

I have a span for RESTAURANT (text) which needs to have a border-bottom that is divided into two but will not overlap the text below it. It's like this picture: [image]

I want to know how to create the divided border beside "bar & lounge" (in the link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to create this is to use CSS `:before` and `:after`.
You can wrap this text in one `<span>spoon and fork</span>` Or you can create two paragraphs, its you decision.

Then you can use :before and :after

```
<p>Spoon and fork</p>

p {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}

p::before, p::after {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  height: 3px;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: wow it's working!! the problem is it's not in the middle of the text.
it looks like this:  ___   spoon & fork   ___ .

Comment: how can i make this as ----  spoon & fork ---- ???
sorry if i'm so noob

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```css
h2{text-align:center}
.custom { width:100%; text-align:center; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; line-height:0.1em; margin:10px 0 20px; } 
.custom span { background:#fff; padding:0 10px; }
```

```html
<h2>MARINA'S RESTAURANT</h2>
<h2 class="custom"><span>Spoon and Fork</span></h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use before and after pseudo element

```css
.block{
width:350px;
text-align:center;
margin:0px auto;}
.text,.text2{
position:relative;
display:block;
font-size:28px;
text-transform:uppercase;}
.text:before{
content:'';
position:absolute;
border:2px solid #000000;
top:50%;
right:0px;
width:45px;}
.text:after{
content:'';
position:absolute;
border:2px solid #000000;
top:50%;
left:0px;
width:45px;}
```

```html
<div class="block">
<span class="text2">Marina's restaurant</span><br/> <span class="text">spoon and fork</span></div>
```